# debugging a database query in the context of Drupal development

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

I am developing a dynamic web page using Drupal 7. I ran into a very strange problem. I have reduced my problem to a very small test case as follows:

The database side: I am using MySQL. I have two tables as defined here with a few sample data entries:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
  pid INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO people VALUES (NULL, 'Joe');
INSERT INTO people VALUES (NULL, 'Ant');
INSERT INTO people VALUES (NULL, 'Tom');

CREATE TABLE event (
  eid INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  pid INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  event_desc VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  event_date DATE NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO event VALUES (NULL, 1, '1p', '2015-10-01');
INSERT INTO event VALUES (NULL, 2, '1p', '2015-10-12');
INSERT INTO event VALUES (NULL, 2, '2p', '2015-10-00');
INSERT INTO event VALUES (NULL, 2, '3p', '2015-00-00');
INSERT INTO event VALUES (NULL, 3, '1p', '2010-07-18');
INSERT INTO event VALUES (NULL, 3, '2p', '2010-09-00');
```

Note the only interesting feature here is that the event table may contain incomplete event date in the format of '2015-10-00' when date is unknown and '2015-00-00' when both date and month are unknown. I understand this is legal in MySQL.

The Drupal 7 side: I create a custom module as follows:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function test_menu() {
  $items['test'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'title' => 'Test',
    'description' => 'Test',
    'page callback' => '_test_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
  );
  return $items;
}

function _test_page() {
  $output = "";
  $sql = "SELECT event.event_desc, event.event_date, people.name FROM  event, ";
  $sql .= "people WHERE event.pid=people.pid ORDER BY people.name";
  $result = db_query($sql);
  foreach ($result as $data) {
    $output .= $data->name. " ". $data->event_desc. " ". $data->event_date. "<br>\n";
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Note that I create a page with a menu item 'Test'. The page performs a query and displays the result. Now the very strange part: when the event date is incomplete, the query gets the wrong data '0000-00-00' as shown in the screen capture below:
[image]

Some analysis:

- This does not seem to be a problem with my SQL, because when I try the
  identical query from mysql command line I can get the correct result.
- This only happens when I join the two tables. If I simply query the 'event' table, I can get the correct result display in that Drupal page.
- When passing the SQL from a standalone PHP script to the database via PDO, there's no problem.
- I learned from Drupal's forum that the Date type is not used in Drupal core. So it may or may not be well supported.

Because the debugging isn't straight-forward to do, I decided not to pursue it any longer. The simplest way around the bug was to use VARCHAR(10) to store the Date information. By making that simple change, my web page can function properly. Of course I would lose the ability to use any Date-related functions.

Comment: Drupal proxies everything straight through to PDO with `db_query`, so no, it's not the DB layer. Why are you concatenating strings to produce SQL rather than actually using the abstraction layer, though?

Comment: I just try to keep the code I post here as short as possible. Is coding the SQL as a string the problem?

Comment: So this isn't the actual code that's causing the problem? Or you've run this snippet too and it produces the same problem, and you're using 'proper' code in the full project, but they produce the same results? Something else?

Comment: You are seeing the actual code. I also want to add that I set up a clean Drupal installation to test the code, producing the screenshot. My real code is of course much more complex.

Comment: Gotcha - I would quickly test that same SQL against a standard PDO object, and see if there are any differences in results. The idea is that there shouldn't be in a blank Drupal installation, but that will at least let you know if it's a Drupal issue or a PDO issue. The code is so straightforward it's hard to imagine how it could be an issue in Drupal

Comment: Clive thanks for the suggestion. I am not an expert so would you please explain: are you suggesting me to write a standalone PHP script outside the Drupal framework, using the API documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Exactly - it should only be a few lines of code and it'll let you know whether there's something you need to change in your use of the Drupal API, or if the query needs to change to make PDO happy with the partial date column

Comment: Well, running the query directly via PDO in a standalone PHP page produces the correct result. Is that suggesting a Drupal problem?

Answer (score 0):

'2015-00-00' is legal in mysql. I wonder if is legal in PHP. What is the data type of $data->event_date ? Just make sure to print it as string and not as a formatted date.

Comment: I tried different ways to process the result set. It looks like the incorrect result is already in the result set. So no matter how I process it I get the same incorrect output. As I mentioned in my original post, if I query the 'event' table only I can get the correct output. So the way I use PHP to traverse the result set is not to blame.